# BASH XDOTool Mouse click, repeat and stop

Tags: bash, xdotool

I am trying to integrate a simple infinite click script using XDOToool with another piece of script to detect keyboard input; to end the running clicking script when a key is pressed but unsure how to match them up.

This script runs infinitely repetitively clicking at screen cursor point XXX, YYY determined by XDOTool

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while true [ 1 ]; do
 xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1 &
 sleep 1.5
 done
```

Next I wish to use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi
count=0
keypress=''
while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do
let count+=1
echo -ne $count'\r'
keypress="`cat -v`"
done
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
echo "You pressed '$keypress' after $count loop iterations"
echo "Thanks for using this script."
exit 0
```

I don't understand how I take the:

```
 xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1 &
 sleep 1.5
```

And where to put it in the script above, BASH confusion and MAN BASH doesn't help so anyone who could assist would be appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 5):

Improved (and commented) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

x_pos="0"   # Position of the mouse pointer in X.
y_pos="0"   # Position of the mouse pointer in Y.
delay="1.5" # Delay between clicks.

# Exit if not running from a terminal.
test -t 0 || exit 1

# When killed, run stty sane.
trap 'stty sane; exit' SIGINT SIGKILL SIGTERM

# On exit, kill this script and it's child processes (the loop).
trap 'kill 0' EXIT

# Do not show ^Key when pressing Ctrl+Key.
stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0

# Infinite loop...
while true; do
    xdotool mousemove "$x_pos" "$y_pos" click 1 &
    sleep "$delay"
done & # Note the &: We are running the loop in the background to let read to act.

# Pause until reads a character.
read -n 1

# Exit.
exit 0
```